# ¿Qué páginas wiki de etiquetas reciben más visitas?

Tags: característica-nueva, estadísticas, wiki-de-etiqueta

Cada etiqueta del sitio tiene una página wiki asociada. Por ejemplo la etiqueta Bash [bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) la tiene en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info (vacía a día de hoy).

Como se explica en la página de privilegios de [Usuario de confianza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> Los Wikis de etiquetas son una introducción general a un tema definido por esa etiqueta. Son un lugar para consolidar y formar una sub-comunidad alrededor de una etiqueta. Contienen, entre otras cosas, las preguntas más frecuentes en la etiqueta, los usuarios principales de la etiqueta y las mejores respuestas recientes en la etiqueta.

Así pues, parece que es un buen referente para explicar qué es una etiqueta y centralizar informaciones comunes. En Stack Overflow (en inglés) he colaborado en la inclusión de información en etiquetas y por ejemplo [la de Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) tiene un montón de datos útiles: preguntas comunes, enlaces frecuentes, algo de *cómo hacer tal*. En general es una herramienta más usada por usuarios avezados que por los nuevos, pero al menos permite canonizar las preguntas canónicas y así todos remar en el mismo sentido.

Nicolas enlazó [en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50184012#50184012) con [una respuesta de Shog9 en Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472/1983854) en la que habla precisamente de este tema: cuánto se visitan las wiki de etiqueta, que resulta estar bastante relacionado con cuánto se enlazan desde las respuestas.

En base a todo ello: ¿sería posible tener datos sobre qué wikis de etiqueta reciben más visitas? ¿y cuáles son más enlazadas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muchas gracias a [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) por la traducción.

---

Según los datos que he obtenido, aquí tenéis la lista de las 10 wikis más visitadas en Stack Overflow en español:

```
Etiqueta         Vistas
----------------------------
java             1922
javascript       1289
php              1144
c#                893
python            789
android           753
mercadopago       578
сss               511
c++               438
html              432
```

Por lo que sé, no hay manera de consultar en la base de datos el número de enlaces que tiene cada wiki de etiqueta. Ahora bien, podemos obtener estos datos *a mano* utilizando la búsqueda del sitio mismo ([véase un ejemplo de publicaciones que enlazan con stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Astackoverflow.com%2Ftags%2Fjstl%2Finfo&mixed=1)).
Me ha sorprendido ver que ninguna de las wikis de etiqueta de la lista de arriba ha sido mencionada nunca en publicación alguna del sitio. Parece que eso ocurre con la mayoría de las etiquetas.

Parece que tenemos una gran oportunidad para realizar algunos experimentos.
[Sabemos el número de visitas de cada wiki de etiqueta](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/soes-tagwikis/tagwikis_viewcount_16_05_2019.csv), cuándo fueron creadas y que los datos son de hoy 16 de mayo de 2019.

Podemos hacer una de estas cosas:

1. Enlacemos las wiki de etiqueta desde las preguntas y las respuestas y de aquí un tiempo (un año o así) miremos cuánto ha cambiado el número de visitas.
2. Mejoremos las wiki de etiquetas para ver después con qué frecuencia la gente las referencia en sus publicaciones.

Comment: that's great info to have! Thanks a lot for taking the time to dig into it and for the suggestions. I do think this can. work well and will try to do it in the tags I know better (namely [tag:bash] and similars).

Comment: @fedorqui, y en español?

Comment: @Ikabod tienes razón. Dije que gracias por tomarse el tiempo en sacar esta información y proponer propuestas. Yo intentaré hacerlo con las etiquetas que conozco mejor y frecuento más.